# Clean Arcitecture EF Core DbContext project

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-core, asp.net-core-mvc, clean-architecture

Looking for some general guidance around the Clean Architecture approach and EF Core.

I have a Web App (UI) project, Domain/Business project, and my Data/Infrastructure project for all crud operations.

When pulling in and creating a DbContext should the context itself be stored in the Data project and the Entities (table classes) be stored in the Domain/Business project since they have no direct crud options.

Or should the DbContext and corresponding entities (tables) be in the Data project together.

Appreciate any help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should design your domain model classes according to the business requirements and in such a way that business domain invariants can be implemented the most efficient way.

This means ***not to burden any infrastructure concerns on your domain model entities***. This principle can be adhered more easily if you put these classes into the domain project and stuff like DbContext and EFCore configuration classes into the data layer.

You can take a look at a reference [Microsoft reference project](https://github.com/dotnet-architecture/eShopOnWeb) where this approach is being followed.

The [order entity](https://github.com/dotnet-architecture/eShopOnWeb/blob/master/src/ApplicationCore/Entities/OrderAggregate/Order.cs) (here also an *aggregate root*) placed in the core (or business domain} project does not have any infrastructure concerns other than the parameterless private constructor required by EFCore - an acceptable trade-off.

```cs
using Ardalis.GuardClauses;
using Microsoft.eShopWeb.ApplicationCore.Interfaces;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace Microsoft.eShopWeb.ApplicationCore.Entities.OrderAggregate
{
    public class Order : BaseEntity, IAggregateRoot
    {
        private Order()
        {
            // required by EF
        }

        public Order(string buyerId, Address shipToAddress, List<OrderItem> items)
        {
            Guard.Against.NullOrEmpty(buyerId, nameof(buyerId));
            Guard.Against.Null(shipToAddress, nameof(shipToAddress));
            Guard.Against.Null(items, nameof(items));

            BuyerId = buyerId;
            ShipToAddress = shipToAddress;
            _orderItems = items;
        }

        public string BuyerId { get; private set; }
        public DateTimeOffset OrderDate { get; private set; } = DateTimeOffset.Now;
        public Address ShipToAddress { get; private set; }

        // DDD Patterns comment
        // Using a private collection field, better for DDD Aggregate's encapsulation
        // so OrderItems cannot be added from "outside the AggregateRoot" directly to the collection,
        // but only through the method Order.AddOrderItem() which includes behavior.
        private readonly List<OrderItem> _orderItems = new List<OrderItem>();

        // Using List<>.AsReadOnly() 
        // This will create a read only wrapper around the private list so is protected against "external updates".
        // It's much cheaper than .ToList() because it will not have to copy all items in a new collection. (Just one heap alloc for the wrapper instance)
        //https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e78dcd75(v=vs.110).aspx 
        public IReadOnlyCollection<OrderItem> OrderItems => _orderItems.AsReadOnly();

        public decimal Total()
        {
            var total = 0m;
            foreach (var item in _orderItems)
            {
                total += item.UnitPrice * item.Units;
            }
            return total;
        }
    }
}
```

The [order entity database configuration](https://github.com/dotnet-architecture/eShopOnWeb/blob/master/src/Infrastructure/Data/Config/OrderConfiguration.cs) is placed in the infrastructure/data project to instrument the mapping between the domain and database layer keeping the domain project independent from such infrastructure concerns.

```cs
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Metadata.Builders;
using Microsoft.eShopWeb.ApplicationCore.Entities.OrderAggregate;

namespace Microsoft.eShopWeb.Infrastructure.Data.Config
{
    public class OrderConfiguration : IEntityTypeConfiguration<Order>
    {
        public void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<Order> builder)
        {
            var navigation = builder.Metadata.FindNavigation(nameof(Order.OrderItems));

            navigation.SetPropertyAccessMode(PropertyAccessMode.Field);

            builder.OwnsOne(o => o.ShipToAddress, a =>
            {
                a.WithOwner();
                
                a.Property(a => a.ZipCode)
                    .HasMaxLength(18)
                    .IsRequired();

                a.Property(a => a.Street)
                    .HasMaxLength(180)
                    .IsRequired();

                a.Property(a => a.State)
                    .HasMaxLength(60);

                a.Property(a => a.Country)
                    .HasMaxLength(90)
                    .IsRequired();

                a.Property(a => a.City)
                    .HasMaxLength(100)
                    .IsRequired();
            });
        }
    }
}
```

With this you have a clean separation of concerns and can focus on business logic in your business layer, getting better testability of the logic and you are still able to leverage the advantages of EFCore.

Comment: Appreciate the detailed answer.  If I may ask one follow up.  We are coming from a traditional asp.net ef 6 approach with edmx files.  Our company insists on using a db first approach.  Most ef core examples adopt a code first approach.  I have overcome that hurdle and can place the files where I need using EF Core Power Tools.  But I am wondering if that would have any bearing on your opinion here in regards to where the files are placed.  Seems the same logic you have provided above would apply but figure I would verify.  Thanks!

Comment: Where exactly you are placing the files is not as important as making sure that your domain model classes are structured according to the business requirements to best support reflecting the domain and Implementing business logic rather than being based on how the persistence in the database is structured. This also includes using the ubiquitous language for naming classes, methods and fields. If those domain model classes also allow you to unit test it's implements business logic without the burden of a database you are already in a good place, no matter what technology you have to use.

Comment: And although I personally always prefer code first, database first should not get into your way as long as you still have code that follows the domain model. With database first the danger is that people think in terms of relational databases and create those structures that way and then try to scram business logic into those structures. The reason why I want to separate domain logic and persistence concerns - unless there is no complex logic and CRUD will do - is that both are equally important and I want to be able to evolve and tune both parts independently from each other.